# F#, concise way to define map4 using map2 and map3

Tags: f#

This question is for amusement only. Please don't take this question too seriously.

I am currently learning F#, and I am interested to see if there is a concise way to define map4, using existing functions List.map2, List.map3, pipe forward/backward, forward/backward composition, etc.

i.e.

```
let map4 f a b c d = ......
map4 f [a1;a2] [b1;b2] [c1;c2] [d1;d2] 

// output: [f(a1,b1,c1,d1); f(a2,b2,c2,d2)]
```

I can solve this recursively, or by defining a new operator (see the following URL)

http://www.fssnip.net/9W/title/nary-Seqmap-

http://call-with-cc-en.blogspot.sg/2009/04/applicative-functors-mapping-function.html

I can also solve this by combining List.map2 and List.map3, using partially applied functions f(a,b,?,?)

```
let map4 f a b c d =
    List.map3 (fun g y -> g y) (List.map2 f a b) c d
```

I can try to shorten my code above using forward composition (and make it as abstract/confusing as possible)

```
let map4 f a =
    List.map2 f a >> List.map3 id;;

// Output type: f:('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e) ->
// a:'a list -> ('b list -> 'c list -> 'd list -> 'e list)
```

I would like to know if I can shorten it even further by getting rid of the "f" and "a", resulting in:

```
let map4 = ...... (* Use only List.map2, List.map3, |>, |<, >>, <<, etc.*) ..........
```

It will probably make it unnecessarily confusing, but it will be pretty cool. Thank you.

---

EDIT:

Adapting TheInnerLight's answer:

```
let inline (<!>) f xList = List.map f xList

let inline (<*>) gList xList = List.map2 (id) gList xList

let map4 f w x y z = f <!> w <*> x <*> y <*> z
let map5 f v w x y z = f <!> v <*> w <*> x <*> y <*> z
let map6 f u v w x y z = f <!> u <*> v <*> w <*> x <*> y <*> z
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a good use for the applicative style of programming, i.e. using [applicative functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicative_functor).

Just define the `apply` function and some helper operators:

```
module List =
    // val apply : f:('a -> 'b) list -> x:'a list -> 'b list
    let apply f x = List.map2 (fun f x -> f x) f x

    // val inline ( <!> ) : f:('a -> 'b) -> x:'a list -> 'b list
    let inline (<!>) f x = List.map f x

    // val inline ( <*> ) : f:('a -> 'b) list -> x:'a list -> 'b list
    let inline (<*>) f x = apply f x
```

Then use map and apply to define `mapN` functions.

```
    // val map2 : f:('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> x:'a list -> y:'b list -> 'c list
    let map2 f x y = f <!> x <*> y

    // val map3 : f:('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd) -> x:'a list -> y:'b list -> z:'c list -> 'd list
    let map3 f x y z = f <!> x <*> y <*> z

    // val map4 : f:('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e) -> x:'a list -> y:'b list -> z:'c list -> a:'d list -> 'e list
    let map4 f x y z a = f <!> x <*> y <*> z <*> a

    // val map8 : f:('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e -> 'f -> 'g -> 'h -> 'i) -> x:'a list -> y:'b list -> z:'c list -> a:'d list -> b:'e list -> c:'f list -> d:'g list -> e:'h list -> 'i list
    let map8 f x y z a b c d e = f <!> x <*> y <*> z <*> a <*> b <*> c <*> d <*> e
```

As you can see, you can keep adding arguments to define arbitrary `mapN`s to your heart's content.

---

Since the question specifically asks about using `map2` or `map3`, you can do this in the same style although it's a little less concise, e.g:

```
    let map4_2 f x y z a = List.map2 f x y <*> z <*> a

    let map4_3 f x y z a = List.map3 f x y z <*> a
```

Hopefully you get the idea.

---

As a small aside, I think it's worth noting that any monad is automatically an applicative functor, so there is a wide array of types you could use this pattern with, here is an `Async` example.

```
module Async = 
    // val map : f:('a -> 'b) -> x:Async<'a> -> Async<'b>
    let map f x = async.Bind(x, async.Return << f)

    // val apply : f:Async<('a -> 'b)> -> x:Async<'a> -> Async<'b>
    let apply f x = async.Bind(f, fun fe -> map fe x)

    // val inline ( <!> ) : f:('a -> 'b) -> x:Async<'a> -> Async<'b>
    let inline (<!>) f x = map f x

    // val inline ( <*> ) : f:Async<('a -> 'b)> -> x:Async<'a> -> Async<'b>
    let inline (<*>) f x = apply f x

    // val map4 : f:('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e) -> x:Async<'a> -> y:Async<'b> -> z:Async<'c> -> a:Async<'d> -> Async<'e>
    let map4 f x y z a = f <!> x <*> y <*> z <*> a
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is very elegant.

Maybe we can remove the "apply" function, and replace it with:

    ""let inline (<!>) f xList = List.map f xList"", and the second part with

    ""let inline (<*>) gList xList = List.map2 gList xList""

Comment: @CHBen To define the apply operator in terms of `map2` you need to do `let inline (<*>) gList xList = List.map2 (fun f x -> f x) gList xList`, or, if you want it in "golf" form, `let inline (<*>) gList xList = List.map2 (<|) gList xList`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to put in the "(id)".

Also, I tried running your code, I am hoping that "map2 (+) [1;2] [500;600]" will produce an output of [501;602], but I think you have some typo in your code and it produced [501;601;502;602]

Comment: @CHBen Thanks for reminding me.  Not so much a typo as just an additonal complexity: there are *two* applicative instances for `list`.  In Haskell, the standard one is the one that I originally showed, which combines all of the lifted functions with all of the other elements, then there is the `ZipList` version, which is the one that applies elementwise - the one you're interested in.  Sorry for the confusion - I should check code as well as type signatures ;)

Comment: @CHBen There is some further detail here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_functors#ZipList

Answer (score 0):

After lots of experimenting, I come up with the following "point-free" style answer:

```
// Warning: still have "Value Restriction" error
let map4 = List.map2 >> (>>) >> (|>) ((>>) >> (|>) (List.map3 id))
```

Unfortunately, the F# compiler will produce a "Value restriction" error, see:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/

And so, I will settle with:

```
let map4 f = 
    f
    |> (    List.map2 >> (>>) >> (|>) ((>>) >> (|>) (List.map3 id))     )
// val map4: f:('a->'b->'c->'d->'e) -> ('a list -> 'b list -> 'c list -> 'd list -> 'e list)
```